# CloudKit unable to save data using swift convenience API

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I am trying to save a record in the public database using the CloudKit convenience API  . When I run the code it does give me the message "Successfully saved record!". But whwn I check the record using iCloudKit dashboard it does not show that data was saved there . Am I missing something here in my code?

```
import Foundation
import CloudKit

protocol CloudKitDelegate {
    func errorUpdating(error: NSError)
    func modelUpdated()
}


class CloudKitHelper {
    var container : CKContainer
    var publicDB : CKDatabase
    let privateDB : CKDatabase
    var delegate : CloudKitDelegate?

    init() {
        container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
        privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
    }

    func saveRecord(todo : NSString) {
        let todoRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Todos")
        todoRecord.setValue(todo, forKey: "todotext")
        publicDB.saveRecord(todoRecord, completionHandler:{(record, error) in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Error saving record:\(error)")
            } else {
                NSLog("Successfully saved record!")
            }
        })
    }
}
let cloudKitHelper = CloudKitHelper()
cloudKitHelper.saveRecord("my new todo item...")
```

Comment: Code looks OK, are you looking at the right data container in the dashboard?

Comment: @EdwinVermeer gOT IT . A record ID firld was missing. I can now see the  data being updated on the dashboard.